# How to keep app folder structure with webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am using aurelia and webpack to develop an app. (I am quite new to both of these tools).

The folder structure of the aurelia app is:

```
src/
    app/
            app.html
            app.js
    page1/
            page1.html
            page1.js
    page2/
            page2.html
            page2.js
```

The webpack config is currently the what is generated by default by aurelia.

```
    entry: {
    app: [
        // Uncomment next line if you need to support IE11
        // 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill',
        'aurelia-bootstrapper'
    ]
},
mode: production ? 'production' : 'development',
output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: baseUrl,
    filename: production
        ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js'
        : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production
        ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map'
        : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production
        ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
        : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
},
```

The result is a dist folder containing vendor and app chunk and bundle files.

I would like to be able to arrange the webpack output into the same folder structure

```
src/
    app/
            app.bundle.map
            app.chunk.js
    page1/
            page1.bundle.map
            page1.chunk.js
    page2/
            page2.bundle.map
            page2.chunk.js
```

The reason for this structure is to allow me to develop and deploy modules independently.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully undestood your need... but if you want to preserve your source code folders' structure this link might help you to set many different entries:

https://dev.to/bbenefield89/webpack-how-to-create-dynamic-entry-output-paths-1oc9

if you were using rollup instead to bundle your files a easy to set up plugin is this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-multi-input

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.